# how to wait for an output in TCL command before running the next command

Tags: shell, unix, tcl

Situation is that I need to invoke a tool using some command and when the tool completes the run , it produces exit 0 status. More precisely it says the following:

> EXIT STATUS 0

I want to use this exit status 0 to execute my next commands. I mean that I want to wait until tool run is complete and exit 0 status returned. Pseudo code bellow:

```
run this tool command  
wait until exit 0 status is generated by above command>    
do the following
```

Actual Code.

```
     @run           {incr i ; set ET_WORKDIR [lindex $argv $i]
                   set COPY_ET_WORKDIR "exec cp -pRf ${ET_WORKDIR} ET_WORKDIR"
                   puts "Copying the ${ET_WORKDIR} inside $env(PROJECT_WDIR_PATH) workarea"
                   eval $COPY_ET_WORKDIR
                   set run_et "exec et -e  $env(PROJECT_WDIR_PATH)/ET_WORKDIR/runet.atpg &"
                   lsc_msg "I" "ATPG analysis has been started!!!"
                   eval  $run_et

  if [info exist EXIT STATUS 0]  
{set setup "exec mkdir $env(PROJECT_WDIR_PATH)/logs/${logdate}"
 eval $setup
 set setupcopy "exec cp -pRf $env(PROJECT_WDIR_PATH)/ET_WORKDIR/testresults/logs/* $env(PROJECT_WDIR_PATH)/logs/$logdate/."
                   eval $setupcopy
                    exit 0
                     }
}
```

Comment: Is your code _really_ formatted like that? If it is, you'll have to neaten things up before Tcl will run it; Tcl _cares_ about newlines. (If it isn't, cut-n-paste the actual code in and then use the little “this is code” button above the form to mark it up properly as code.)

Answer (score 0):

The execution that you're doing is currently happening in the background, because you've put `&` at the end of

```
set run_et "exec et -e  $env(PROJECT_WDIR_PATH)/ET_WORKDIR/runet.atpg &"
```

If you change that to:

```
set run_et "exec et -e  $env(PROJECT_WDIR_PATH)/ET_WORKDIR/runet.atpg"
```

Tcl will wait until the command finishes running before continuing the script. You can get the output using:

```
set run_et "exec et -e  $env(PROJECT_WDIR_PATH)/ET_WORKDIR/runet.atpg"
set et_output [eval $run_et]
```

Mind you, in this case it would actually be considered good style to write just this:

```
set et_output [exec et -e $env(PROJECT_WDIR_PATH)/ET_WORKDIR/runet.atpg]
```

**Warning!** If `et` produces a non-zero exit code *or* writes to standard error, the `exec` will throw a (`catch`able) error. The best way of dealing with that varies with exactly what `et` is doing, but it is often something a bit like this:

```
if {[catch {exec et -e $env(PROJECT_WDIR_PATH)/ET_WORKDIR/runet.atpg} et_output]} {
    puts "Oh no! Things went wrong! Error message is '$et_output'"
    exit 1
}
```

Or this (Tcl 8.6):

```
try {
    set et_output [exec et -e $env(PROJECT_WDIR_PATH)/ET_WORKDIR/runet.atpg]
} on error msg_var {
    puts "Oh no! Things went wrong! Error message is '$msg_var'"
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you Donal Fellows . This Helps alot.